# Several checkboxes and validation jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am doing a questionnaire with several checkboxes (yes, no) and if all are ´no´ the below fields should be readonly and disabled, but if there are any ´yes´, the fields should be required. All the questionnaire is inside a table and two checkboxes for each tr.

I´m trying many things but I´m sure someone has better ideas than me.

The HTML code is the following:

```
<div class="questionnaire_a">
    <table class="table questionnaire">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Is required?</th>
                <th>YES</th>
                <th>NO</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="quest" class="quest">
                <td>Q1</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="ques_Q1y" name="ques_Q1y" class="table quest_q"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="ques_Q1n" name="ques_Q1n" class="table quest_q"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="quest" class="quest">
                <td>Q2</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="ques_Q2y" name="ques_Q2y" class="table quest_q"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="ques_Q2n" name="ques_Q2n" class="table quest_q"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr  id="quest" class="quest">
                <td>Q3</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="ques_Q3y" name="ques_Q3y" class="table quest_q"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="ques_Q3n" name="ques_Q3n" class="table quest_q"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr  id="quest" class="quest">
                <td>Q4</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="ques_Q4y" name="ques_Q4y" class="table quest_q"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="ques_Q4n" name="ques_Q4n" class="table quest_q"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="fields" class="fields">
     <select class="pos" id="pos" name="pos"></select>
     <input type="number" step="1" class="len" id="len" name="len">
     <input type="number" step="1" class="he" id="he" name="he">
     <select class="perm" id="perm" name="perm"></select>
</div>
```

I want to make the fields below (input and selects) readable or required, depends on the checkboxes. My Jquery script is active when change checkboxes as follows:

```
$("input[type='checkbox'][name^='ques_']:checkbox").change(function() {
     //Code
});
```

When I add a new group:

```
var group = $('#group').clone(),
        group_fields = group.find('input, select,table, td, .questionnaire, questionnaire_a, .quest_q')

   group_fields.each(function() {
        $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + '_' + num);
        $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name') + '_' + num);
```

That´s my way to check when checkboxes are selected, but I don´t know how to know if there are a yes or no and how to count it to make the other fields required or readable.

If any of you have some idea, thank for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to enabled/disable based on whether checkboxes are checked or not. I left the making them required as an exercise, but should be pretty straightforward since I showed how to set a property on the fields.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.1.4" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table class="table questionnaire">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Is required?</th>
                        <th>YES</th>
                        <th>NO</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr id="quest" class="quest">
                        <td>Q1</td>
                        <td><input type="radio" id="ques_Q1y" value="y" class="table quest_q" name="ques_Q1"></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" id="ques_Q1n" value="n" class="table quest_q" name="ques_Q1" checked></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="quest" class="quest">
                        <td>Q2</td>
                        <td><input type="radio" id="ques_Q2y" value="y" class="table quest_q" name="ques_Q2"></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" id="ques_Q2n" value="n" class="table quest_q" name="ques_Q2" checked></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr  id="quest" class="quest">
                        <td>Q3</td>
                        <td><input type="radio" id="ques_Q3y" value="y" class="table quest_q" name="ques_Q3"></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" id="ques_Q3n" value="n" class="table quest_q" name="ques_Q3" checked></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr  id="quest" class="quest">
                        <td>Q4</td>
                        <td><input type="radio" id="ques_Q4y" value="y" class="table quest_q" name="ques_Q4"></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" id="ques_Q4n" value="n" class="table quest_q" name="ques_Q4" checked></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

                <div id="fields" class="fields">
                     <select class="pos" id="pos" name="pos"></select>
                     <input type="number" step="1" class="len" id="len" name="len">
                     <input type="number" step="1" class="he" id="he" name="he">
                     <select class="perm" id="perm" name="perm"></select>
                </div>
  </body>

</html>



$(document).ready(function() {
  var radios = $("input[type='radio'][name^='ques_']");

  radios.change(function() {
    updateFields();
  });

  function updateFields() {
    var enabled = anyYesChecked(radios)
    enableFields(enabled);
  }

  function anyYesChecked(cbs) {
    var anyChecked = false;
    $.each(cbs, function(index, cb) {
      if (cb.value=='y' && cb.checked) anyChecked = true;
    });

    return anyChecked;
  }

  function enableFields(enabled) {
    // enble fields
    $('#pos').prop('disabled', !enabled);
    $('#len').prop('disabled', !enabled);
    $('#he').prop('disabled', !enabled);
    $('#perm').prop('disabled', !enabled);

    // make fields required
    //TODO
  }

  updateFields();
});
```

And here is the plunkr for demo purposes: http://plnkr.co/edit/vYGCrEr4WpTA7b4FdBSq?p=preview

Comment: That is not working for me, because this code check if there are any checkbox selected and then can disable the input field, but I have to differentiate between yes and no to be able to disable or enable fields, but I´m going to modify your code to see if I find the right answer.

Comment: in that case, why not use radio buttons so only yes or no can be selected  (and not both) for each question?

Comment: I solved that with a function, so only can be checked one in the same row.

Comment: I've updated the code to work with radio buttons... I think for the end users this might be more intuitive than checkboxes. Let me know. The plunkr is also updated.

Comment: At the end I had to change it for radio buttons, because using checkboxes is more inestable, even using jQuery, so then the style can be modified using css to look as checkboxes. I´m going to try the validation for several questionnaires, because I have a button that clone the first group of questions and add a number at the end of the name/id.

Comment: I´ve got something weird in the code, but only works for the same, and the radiobuttons values are cloned as well when the questionnaire is clone, I´ve used this inside the clone button to clear the values `block_clone.find('.questionnaire').each(function(k, v) {
        if (k > 0) $(this).remove();
    });` where questionnaire is a new div that I´ve created to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add a "Yes" class to the yes boxes. Inside the event handler for the checkbox change, you could check the number of "Yes" classes checked.
If that number is greater than 0, activate the fields in the fields div and add the required attribute.

```
$("input[type='checkbox'][name^='ques_']:checkbox").change(function() {
   var yes = $(".yes:checked").length;
   if(yes > 0){                              
      $("#fields").children().prop("disabled",false).prop("required",true);
   }
   else{
     $("#fields").children().prop("disabled",true).prop("required",false);
    }
});
```

You could hard code the disabled property on each of the form elements if you want them to start off disabled.

I tested it in jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/seattaball/9hpc73t1/1/

Comment: I like the idea, I´m going to try it if works with my code. Thanks

Comment: Works perfectly with my code and it´s the easiest way to do it.  I´m trying to do it for many names and fields but does not work. I'm saying `$("input[id^='fields'][id*=['"+$rowY+"']]") ` when the id has a format like this: "fields_X_rowY", where X can be anything and rowY is autoincremment.

Comment: If nothing else begins with "fields_" but the controls you are trying to validate, you should be able to use:   $("input[id^='fields_'])  as the selector. This will restrict selection to input elements, and restrict selection of inputs to those that have a prefix of "fields" with an underscore.

Comment: If that doesn't help, could you share your HTML and JavaScript code, please?

Comment: Yes,  I could use that, the problem is for the second table the name is _2 and for the thrid _3, so there is no difference between tables and the ideal would be to validate each table with their inputs fields. For example if I fill the second table will have validate only the second group of inputs, but using that code if you answer the second questionnaire the required or readable fields is the same for the next tables.

Comment: Could you select the tablefirst, then find the children?

Comment: Could you select the table  by the numeric suffix first, then find the child elements? $("table[id$='_2']").find("input").each(function(){ do this for each one....}); ?

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `.index()` , `Array.prototype.some`

```js
var input = $("input[type=checkbox][name^=ques_]:checkbox")
, fields = $("#fields").find("input, select");

input.change(function(e) {
  var res = Array.prototype.some.call(input, function(elem, idx) {
    return $(elem).parent().index() === 2 && elem.checked
  });
  console.log($(this).parent().index(), res);
  if (res) {
    fields
    .each(function(i, el) {
      el.disabled = true;
      el.readonly = true;
      el.required = false;
    })
  } else {
    fields
    .each(function(i, el) {
      el.disabled = false;
      el.readonly = false;
      el.required = true;
    })
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<table class="table questionnaire">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Is required?</th>
      <th>YES</th>
      <th>NO</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="quest" class="quest">
      <td>Q1</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="ques_Q1y" name="ques_Q1y" class="table quest_q">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="ques_Q1n" name="ques_Q1n" class="table quest_q">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="quest" class="quest">
      <td>Q2</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="ques_Q2y" name="ques_Q2y" class="table quest_q">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="ques_Q2n" name="ques_Q2n" class="table quest_q">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="quest" class="quest">
      <td>Q3</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="ques_Q3y" name="ques_Q3y" class="table quest_q">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="ques_Q3n" name="ques_Q3n" class="table quest_q">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="quest" class="quest">
      <td>Q4</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="ques_Q4y" name="ques_Q4y" class="table quest_q">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="ques_Q4n" name="ques_Q4n" class="table quest_q">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div id="fields" class="fields">
  <select class="pos" id="pos" name="pos"></select>
  <input type="number" step="1" class="len" id="len" name="len">
  <input type="number" step="1" class="he" id="he" name="he">
  <select class="perm" id="perm" name="perm"></select>
</div>
```